# Using BigQuery to run a Monte Carlo simulation that is too big for excel

Tags: google-bigquery, probability, rank, montecarlo

I have been experimenting with linear regression to predict future test scores for students. I have also found a couple of distributions that would potentially fit my data and that I would like to use further to run a Monte Carlo simulation.

The basic outline of my Monte Carlo simulation is to simulate each student's test score over a large number of simulations. I would then like to use the scores for each simulation to rank students in specific classes, such as top of the class, second place etc.

In excel, I have been achieving this and I have been using the 'countifs' function to rank the position of students in each class, and then count how many times each student finished top of the class among the large sample of simulations. This has been a first draft and it looks like it is heading in a direction that I am happy with so far.

My problem is this - the size of my sample is too big for it to run the simulated test scores and countifs/rank on excel efficiently. I have run the simulations seperately to ease the workload on the excel files but it is still too slow. I am wondering if this can be achieved in BigQuery instead? I have been learning some of the basics of BigQuery and it has been easy and enjoyable to use so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share a small sample of the data you are using as input and what the desired output for that data would be along with and SQL that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simulation of student grades. Each `grade` is between 0 and 99. 99 is the highest grade. We simulate 25 student `id`s and 20 tests `run`. Each test is taken by all students and the results are random. The complete list is saved in a tempory table, this can be used to do further analysis of the results. Each run returns other results and also the use in CTE (With) may lead to different results due to recalculation.

```sql
With tbl as 
(Select 
  id, 
  round(rand()*100) as grade,
  run
  from 
    unnest(generate_array(1,25)) as id,
    unnest(generate_array(1,20)) as run 
)


Select * ,
rank() over (partition by run order by grade desc) as rank

from tbl

order by run, grade desc
```

The `rank` window function wants to have an area to create the rank on, here it each test, definded by `run`. Then the rank shall be ordered by the `grade`.